# Javascript not executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really could not understand why the 'alert' javascript is not executed on my page...

When clicking on the first step menu, the second one is well displayed as expected but from this point no more javascript is executed and I could not get the alert displayed.

This simple page is using Jquery to remove/add a class.

Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello world with jQuery</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displayStep2() {
            $("#searchStep1").addClass("displayNone");
            $("#searchStep2").removeClass("displayNone");
        }
        function displayStep3() {
            alert('Hello, world!');step
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="searchContainer">
    <div id="searchStep1">
        <h2>Step1:</h2>
        <ul id="searchList1">
            <li id="search11" onclick="displayStep2()"><span>1.1</span></li>
            <li id="search12" onclick="displayStep2"><span>1.2</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="searchStep2" class="displayNone">
        <h2>Step2:</h2>
        <ul id="searchList2">
            <li id="search21" onclick="displayStep3"><span>2.1</span></li>
            <li id="search22" onclick="displayStep3"><span>2.2</span></li>
            <li id="search23" onclick="displayStep3"><span>2.3</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="searchStep3" class="displayNone">
        <h2>Step3:</h2>
        <ul id="searchList3">
            <li id="search31" onclick=""><span>3.1</span></li>
            <li id="search32" onclick=""><span>3.2</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
.displayNone{
    display: none   
}
```

Is somone could help me not to become crazy...?!

Comment: You need to add parentheses to `onclick`-bound functions, but you should really just rip out those [DOM0 events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#DOM_Level_0) and instead [bind them with jQuery.](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: Try putting brackets after the methods displayStep3 so displayStep3()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write `displayStep3();` instead of `displayStep3`. The latter is no function call.

Comment: My god... I'm tired! Sorry about that.